# How to test the values of an XML file against a list of expected values?

Tags: xml, automation

I am testing an API for a website.  I wrote a Selenium Webdriver script to change all of the fields for one customer record in the UI.

When I make a call to the API, it exports a list of customers to an XML file.

Is there a tool I can use validate that the API is exporting an XML file with the expected values for a particular record?

Sample of a record as it appears in the XML File:

```
<data>
<row><member_id>3bed8459-b581-52ed-0a12-53c088c55033</member_id>
<id>47ea91b3-379c-7153-1469-53c08b656327</id>
<date_modified>2014-07-12 01:11:14</date_modified>
<deleted>0</deleted>
<first_name>Aaron</first_name>
<last_name>Evddns</last_name>
<phone_mobile/>
<phone_work/>
<hire_date_c/>
<professional_designation_c>DDS</professional_designation_c>
<pte_fte_c/>
<salary_c/>
<title_1_c>Owner/Provider</title_1_c>
<gender_c>male</gender_c>
<status_c>Active</status_c>
<primary_location_c>None</primary_location_c>
<status_comments_c/>
<accreditation_c/>
<termination_date_c/>
<secondary_location_c/>
<email1>dhats@ungentaldental.com</email1>
</row>
```

For example:

```
For member_id '3bed8459-b581-52ed-0a12-53c088c55033'
validate id = '47ea91b3-379c-7153-1469-53c08b656327'
validate deleted = 0
validate first_name = 'Aaron'
validate last_name = 'Evans'
```

Comment: What is a customer 1001?

Comment: "Is there any tool I can use to automate the process of verifying that the values for customer 1001 in the XML file match the set of values that should now be assigned to the fields?" -- Can you elaborate this.

Comment: I know what the values in the XML file should be, I want to write a script to validate that the values are correct.  I added a small psuedocode example above.

Even if you know what a name for this process would be called.  My searches for XML validation or testing XML have been turning up tests for validating the structure of the XML file but not verifying values.

Comment: What language are you using when writing your Selenium scripts?

Comment: C#.  I don't have to incorporate the selenium webdriver UI test with the XLM validation test.  So, I could use any tool language to validate the XML file.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure about a tool to do that but you can definitely use C# `XmlDocument` Class to do the job. You can find the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can probably just iterate over the elements in your output XML and compare the values of the keys to the values you have used to fill in the data using your Webdriver script.